How can I getLiveCharts Angular Gauge (click, mouse etc) Events to work . The Events are not raised
I have an application  with livecharts in winforms in vb.net.
I use the Gauge control and I get some gauges to display.
I want to add the gauages dynamically but for the test, I already tried both.
The gauges just do not trigger any events: The double click, click, mouseover, mousedown etc.. All these events are not raised.
Am I doing something wrong?
like described, I have tried it with dynamically  Angular gauges and I tried it with dragging them on the form.. Neither of them raised any events.
Is it a setting?
